Is it possible to know if face contains a white pixel using geometry nodes?
Long story short: I want to check if there is a white pixel inside a face on the texture. If it does have one -> subdivide it. If it does not contain white pixels -> leave it the same.
Is it possible to do it using geometry nodes?
B&W picture:

Expect mesh:


I think you'll need some image-processing , after UV map definition.. maybe some Python. Would it help to ask what this is for , in case there is another way?

Sure, i want to create adaptive subdiv modifier for displacement maps, i will mark places i want to be more detailed with white color, but with default tools color attribute it shows only color of pixel at exact face coordinates

Could the detection of regions requiring more subduv. be automated in some way.. do they share some characteristic, or is it a purely human decision?

actually i wanted to test it out in blender and then write it using c# or python, but feels like i need to do it this way from scratch

It does sound like that... if the external processing fits into your pipeline, and Blender is only to test .. I think the Blender Python API is the only way to go, inside the application, so you may as well go external straight away.  That's my feeling, but it doesn't make me right.

Could you provide a Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ including an image, a mesh and a texture associated ? And add to your question a picture illustrating the "face" you would like to subdivide ? It does not have to be your real case. A manufactured one, but representative, is fine.

Mesh is actually a simple plane, so i am not sure if you really need a file. Let's say we have a black and white image with some picture at the center, i want to subdivide all the faces, where white pixel is "inside" the face we check. In the perfect algorithm i should start with only one face, that's the actual problem ATM
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yKisZGT__HWUNmh0aJur9RPKE8U1ZOz7/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Oc4MhgerInOkpGE6P0V-3l32u5kORh6/view?usp=sharing
Here is screenshot of example though

Could you please add your images (they are perfect to understand your objective) inside your question, not through a link in a comment ? Thanks.

sure, there you go
